# ngModel not binding to tinymce in angular 5

Tags: angular, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am integrated tinymce in angular 5 project, it working fine but data binding is not working. how can i achieve data binding with tinymce in angular5 project. I am trying binding 'tinymce' text editor with 'ngmodel'. i am not able to do. can you please help me any one. i have tried bellow code.

### html

```
    <editor [(ngModel)]="dataModel"></editor>
```

### script

```
import { EditorModule } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    EditorModule // <- Important part
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: any error in the console?

Comment: No, ever thing working but data binding is not working  [(ngModel)]="dataModel

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import `FormsModule` in `app.module.ts`.

```
import { EditorModule } from '@tinymce/tinymce-angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    EditorModule,
    FormsModule // <--- here
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Tinymce integration is done, working fine but data is not binding that like  [(ngModel)]="dataModel", can you please help me

Comment: Did you define dataModel in your component.ts file? Or whatever name are you binding data to?

Answer (score 0):

data binding should work fine with already mentioned up, but here is again.

```
<editor [(ngModel)]="textdata" apiKey="your api key" [init]="{plugins: 'link'}"></editor>
```

If you print it in html like {{textdata}} you will get all with tags.